# JavaScript regex replace as alphanumeric with spaces only between character groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I do not have much experience with JavaScript regex and am unsure how to only allow an input to have alphanumeric characters with a single space between groups of these characters.

Some examples of what is desirable:

```
"abcde"
"ab cde"
"ab c de"
```

Some examples of what is undesirable:

```
" abcde"
"abcde "
"ab   c   de"
```

I realize that I could use `trim()` to handle the first and last cases, `split(" ")`, and then only concatenate non-empty strings but want to know how to do this with regex.

On a side note, I am fine with using `\w` to represent allowable characters, "_" is not a problem.

Comment: Do you want to disallow the input (ie match only the good cases), or fix the broken ones?

Comment: Fix the broken ones, ideally as they are being typed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to fix the bad cases, you can use something like the following:

```
text = text.replace(/^ +| +$|( ) +/g, "$1");
```

The `/^ +/` will match one or more spaces at the beginning, `/ +$/` will match one or more spaces at the end, and `/( ) +/` will match two or more spaces anywhere in the string.  The capture group will be an empty string for the first two expressions but it will be a single space for `( ) +` so you will replace multiple spaces with just one.

Comment: This does work with text that has already been entered but I was hoping to do it as the text was being typed, it seems like the " +$" will not allow it, any way around this?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I cannot do this while it is being typed as someone will type a space for the next group of characters. I was able to change yours a bit to this `replace(/^ +|( ) +/g, "$1")` which allows one space at the end. Thank you for explaining